# Is there a way to dynamically map callbacks to a GestureDetector Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

So basically I want to know if there is a way or a package (couldn't find one) that allows the dynamic mapping of functions that are passed through the Widgets constructor that contains the GestureDetector-Widget.

If I could define the GestureDetector-Widget prior to its usage I would not have a problem, but mostly everything is final in this widget.

Defining the GestureDetector in a Function isn't an option as well, even though it would alleviate me from the "final"-restrictions stuff since I face some other restrictions there that don't matter for this stackoverflow question.

I know I could just make them available in the constructor of the widget but if I expose everything in the constructor it'd be way too overloaded.
I'd like something like a map with some key and a Function as value.
maybe as an enum so you don't make a typo in that string key :)

and then passing it along to the widget that contains the GestureDetector-Widget which then passes it to the GestureDetector-Widget constructor.

Why do I want such complicated things?
Glad you asked.
At the moment I am making a package as well and I want to give developers the possibility to overwrite most of the default behaviour so they can overwrite nearly everything if they need to expand it (at least that's the plan :D)
But let's say they just want to add a callback to something in the gesturedetector that I didn't include as default behaviour. At the moment they'd have to overwrite 2 Widgets only to get some gesture functionality and that doesn't seem right.
The problem is that the Widgets that reacts to gestures is initialized by another "Container" like widget and it handles some callbacks that only can be defined in this "Container" like widget, since the callback depends on some variables and Methods from that widget.
Somehow this feels like I am fighting the framework...

If there is no basic way and no package to do this I'd write another package that does exactly that but I am hoping I don't have to...

So do you know a way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you have `GestureDetector` with only one (for example `onTap`) callback and you would like the users to add `onPanStart` or `onPanUpdate` at runtime?

Comment: @pskink something like that.If the developer uses my package and defines another callback the allocation of the callback function from the gesture detector wouldn't be fix so I guess the GestureDetector would get his functions allocated at runtime. Isn't that exactly the same with normal gesture detecor callback allocation, but instead of having a fixed VoidCallbackFunction variable that will be added to onTap I'd like some algorithm before the function allocation. I wrote somewhere in my post that I could expose the onTap, onDoubleTap, etc., but this would make the constructor look more neat.